# How to determine when a fragment is visible to the user

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

my app has one activity called MainActivity.

MainActivity loads 3 fragments, all added to back stack. The first one is automatically opened and is ListFragment. If I click on an item in ListFragment the DetailFragment is created. Inside DetailF I can click the edit button and EditFragment is opened. So the backstack is:

- ListFragment
- DetailFragment
- EditFragment

Inside EditF one can change informations about the object that is being displayed in DetailFragment. Inside the onPause of EditF I save the chanegs

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();        
    mTask.setTitle(mTitleEditText.getText().toString());
    mTask.setSummary(mSummaryEditText.getText().toString());

}
```

So when I hit the back button the chanegs are successfully saved (I see that from the logs). So DetailF appears but the changes are not shown: that's becuase DetailF has been previously loaded with the beggining data. Since the onresume doesn't get called when DetailF is visible I can't tell the fragment to update the data.

If I hit the back button another time I go back to the ListF and the updated data is also not shown.

This is how I create the fragemnts:

in MainActivity.java

```
private void launchListFragment(){

    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack ("detail", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

    Fragment newDetail = ListFragment.newInstance();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, newDetail, "LIST_F_TAG")
            .commit();
}
```

in ListFragment:

```
Task taskToSend = mViewAdapter.getList().get(adapterPosition);

        if(getActivity() != null){
            Fragment newDetail = DetailFragment.newInstance(taskToSend);
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, newDetail)
                    .addToBackStack("detail")
                    .commit();
        }
```

in DetailFragment:

```
private void launchEditFragment(Task task){
    if(getActivity() != null){
        Fragment newDetail = EditFragment.newInstance(task);
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, newDetail)
                .addToBackStack("edit")
                .commit();
    }
}
```

I want that once I update the mTask data in EditFragment all other fragments display the updated data. Thanks.

Comment: Are you certain `onPause` is called and then `onResume` isn't called?  If I understand right, it's not possible for a fragment to be paused and then displayed again without calling `onResume`.

Comment: The fragment never goes in onPause or onResume, since its lifecycle is tied to its activity. Since the activity manages more fragments but never gets paused (except for app close) then the fragment is always running as if it was visible even if it isn't.

Comment: I see, I thought fragments were paused when obscured like activities.  Are you managing the back stack, or letting the system do that?

Comment: I just solved the problem switching to activities. It is much less problematic and I don't want to waste time re-inventing the wheel to get a simple onPause working on a fragment.